# Mypy: Incompatible types in assignment for property setter

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I want to use `property setter` with mypy.
The types of propetry getter and setter are different:

```py
from typing import List, Iterable

class Foo:
    @property
    def x(self) -> List[int]:
        ...

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x: Iterable[int]):
        ...

foo = Foo()
foo.x = (1, 2, 3) # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, int, int]", variable has type "List[int]")
```

How do I handle this error?

Comment: Please add a minimal definition for both methods. Likely, `mypy` is following the assignment to and the use of the underlying attribute, and discovering that you are trying to return the original tuple as a list. For example, `self._x = new_x` in the setter then `return self._x` in the getter.

Comment: tracking issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3004

Answer (score 1):

Mypy complains that types are incompatible because Tuple has different signature:

```
# For tuples, we specify the types of all the elements
x: Tuple[int, str, float] = (3, "yes", 7.5)
```

In case of setters and getters if you just assign input parameter of a setter to a class variable, type should be the same. Iterable[int] and Tuple[int,int,int] are different types, because in this case tuple is immutable object and has 3 elements.

The way to handle this error is to convert tuple to list before setting to foo.x:

```
foo.x = list((1,2,3))
```

Comment: Either the setter or the getter can also perform the conversion, rather than making the caller do it.

Comment: I don't want users to do it. I've defined the setter to have different type signature from getter because the setter can actually accept all Iterable, and convert it internally.

Comment: I tried to convert types in setter, but seems like Mypy is checking types before getting into the function.